# Requesting xAuth permission from Twitter API Policy

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine, xauth

Twitter API Policy team requires iOS app developer to apply for permission to use xAuth. They suggest me to use oAuth first, but as I'm using MGTwitterEngine, I am unable to use oAuth as communication, except when I use my consumer key & consumer secret .

But using the consumer key & consumer secret , I can only post to my Twitter, instead of allowing users to login with their account.

What have I missed in xAuth application process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems iOS 5 has native Twitter support, therefore problem is then solved ( only in iOS 5 ). Still waiting for answers for iOS 4.

Answer (score 0):

If your application support custom login for twitter, Then you need to mail twitter guys saying that your application support custom login etc,etc  feature.

Mail should contain

Consumer key,Secret key  etc.

Put the valid reason why you need Xauth key for your application.

Comment: I did that before. Twitter API Policy team said I have to submit the app to Apple then apply for Twitter xAuth again. But, I want to have Twitter support in the 1st version.